# How to install openstack havana (compute) in centos?

Tags: centos, openstack

I am working openstack havana, so how do I install openstack havana on centOS?

When i try to install it I get this error:

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

base: centos.excellmedia.net

epel: ftp.riken.jp

extras: centos.excellmedia.net

updates: centos.excellmedia.net

21 packages excluded due to repository priority protections

No package python-software-properties available.

Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems  python-software-properties is not installed in the machine. Use the below command and install python-software-properties first.

`apt-get install python-software-properties`

`add-apt-repository cloud-archive:havana`

Update the package database, upgrade your system, and reboot for all changes to take effect:

`apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`

`reboot`

Then try with the installation of openstack.